# SQL - Show point instead of comma as decimal separator

Tags: sql

```
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(FF.AlinanFF AS MONEY), 1) AS VARCHAR) AlinanFF
```

Data is shown in this format:

```
AlinanFF
2,642.11
```

I want to display the data in this way:

```
AlinanFF
2.642,11
```

`'AlinanFF'` format nvarchar

Comment: have you tried replace() function?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product

Comment: If you're using a recent version of SQL Server, you can use the FORMAT function, specifying a culture that has the separators you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you ! 

CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), CAST(FF.AlinanFF AS money), 1),1,LEN(CONVERT(varchar(20), CAST(FF.AlinanFF AS money), 1))-3), ',','.') + REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(20), CAST(FF.AlinanFF AS money), 1),3), '.',',') AS VARCHAR(20)) AS AlinanFF,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING('2,642.11',1,CHARINDEX('.','2,642.11')-1),',','.')+REPLACE(SUBSTRING('2,642.11',CHARINDEX('.','2,642.11'),1000),'.',',') as AlinanFF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('2,642.11','.','^'),',','.'),'^',',') AS AlinanFF
```